# How do I add opacity on touchdown in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I want to achieve opacity on the touchdown event. I have attached the code below. This code is adding color to the tap of a button. How do I ensure that instead of color only opacity should work?

```
// Button touchdown event
@IBAction func touchdown(_ sender: UIButton) {
    continueOutlet.setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor(named: "hover")!, forState: .highlighted)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also modify the alpha of the color inside the storyboard only.

**see attached image**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change the alpha component of the color you need.

```
@IBAction func touchdown(_ sender: UIButton) {
    continueOutlet.setBackgroundColor(color: continueOutlet.backgroundColor!.withAlphaComponent(0.5), forState: .highlighted)
}
```

Comment: But what if I don't need any color and just opacity? Is this not possible? I've been told about alpha component opacity too.

Comment: What do you mean by opacity without color? Did you mean changing the opacity of the existing background color?

Comment: Yes for example, on tap to a button add opacity of 0.5 to the existing bg color?

Comment: Check out the update. It now updates the opacity of the exiting bg color.